Fit Negative Binomial Mixed-Effects model with instrumental variables with R
How can I fit a Fixed-Effects Negative Binomial model with instrumental variables with R?
I have tried fixest package, but it only supports instrumental variables for OLS, not for negative binomial:
id <- rep(seq(1,10), each=5)
year <- rep(seq(2021, 2025), times=10)
df <- data.frame(id=id, year=year)
df[["weight"]] <- rnorm(nrow(df), 100, 10)
df[["height"]] <- 2*df$weight+rnorm(nrow(df), 0, 5)
df[["count"]] <- rpois(nrow(df), df$height+rnorm(nrow(df), 0, 5))
mod <- fixest::fenegbin(count ~ 1 | id | height~weight, df)

Error in fixest::fenegbin(count ~ 1 | id | height ~ weight, df) : 
  The argument 'fml' cannot contain more than two parts separated by a pipe ('|'). IVs are available only for 'feols'.
The syntax is: DEP VAR ~ EXPL VARS | FIXED EFFECTS. (No IVs allowed.)

Related: IV regression in Fixed-Effect Models with diagnostics

This is much more appropriate for https://stats.StackExchange.com. Once you have a specific task unambiguously described on a theoretical level, then coding can begin.
